# Selenium in Instapy ( path ) error , while everything is set up

Tags: python, selenium

I just downloaded Instapy and I decided to give it a try , but I get an error about Selenium, while I have multiple selenium paths , even a path thats here : instabot\assets\chromedriver , but I still get this error. Do you guys have any idea where can be a problem ? + what about that PermissionsError ? ( I was looking for it but couldnt find it )

Btw I am running the CMD as an administrator so problem isnt there that I dont have admin permissions

```
ERROR [2018-03-31 01:01:06] [XXXXXXXXX]  Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\instabot\instapy\instapy.py", line 256, in set_selenium_local_session
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\instabot\instapy\instapy.py", line 256, in set_selenium_local_session
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 22, in <module>
    multi_logs=True)
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\instabot\instapy\instapy.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.set_selenium_local_session()
  File "C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\instabot\instapy\instapy.py", line 260, in set_selenium_local_session
    Settings.chromedriver_location))
instapy.instapy.InstaPyError: ensure chromedriver is installed at C:\Users\StyleZ\PycharmProjects\instabot\assets\chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys :) I fixed it :) Because I have a windows I had to use an absolute path ,so instead of :

```
chromedriver_location = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'chromedriver')
```

i had to use :

```
chromedriver_location = os.path.join("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
```